# Python how to mock envvars in the test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Hi guys my actual method uses envvars which will be set as a constant

```
  PERSONAL_ID = os.getenv("PERSONAL_ID")
  PATH_NAME = os.getenv("PATH_NAME")
```

I use this envvar in my method (not as a input parameter) and now I try to test it but during the assert I get "None"

I have tried this above my test:

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"PERSONAL_ID ": "123", "PATH_NAME": "test_path"})
```

Comment: Can you show the full body of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this was caused by a typo, remove space at the end of `PERSONAL_ID`:

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"PERSONAL_ID": "123", "PATH_NAME": "test_path"})
```

This example works:

```
import os


def uses_env_vars():
    return os.getenv('PERSONAL_ID')


@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"PERSONAL_ID": "123", "PATH_NAME": "test_path"}, clear=True)
def test_uses_env_vars():
    assert uses_env_vars() == os.environ["PERSONAL_ID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to "mock" the environment variables. You can just set them to an appropriate value:

```
os.environ['PERSONAL_ID'] = '123'
os.environ['PATH_NAME'] = 'test_path'
```

These will only be visible within your tests (because that's just how environment variables work -- they can be seen in the current process and its children).

Comment: it still returns None :/

Comment: If you update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can provide you with better answers.